# keras Dense Artificial Nueral network Hidden Layers: Not able to create a suitable model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I am trying to create a simple ANN with this data: 2 columns (say height and weight) and a target column (say age, which is continuous). I dont know how many hidden layers to have in the model. When I run the attached code, the accuracy is  low as shown in the output i'm getting (so I am assuming I have not constructed a suitable model).

```
#ann
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
data=bothratings_Comp3f2bda12d278f24b211e34ede243dd32_final
data

X = pd.DataFrame(data.iloc[:, 0:2].values)
y = data.iloc[:, 1].values
X
y

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 0)

import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=2, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))
model.summary()
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam', metrics=['mse','mae'])
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=150, batch_size=50,  verbose=1, validation_split=0.2)
```

Below is the output I am getting across the epochs-. What changes do I make to get a reducing loss as the training progresses and to get better accuracy

```
"classifier = Sequential()\nclassifier.add(Dense(units=2,activation = 'relu'))\nclassifier.add(Dense(units=1,activation = 'sigmoid'))\nclassifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])\nclassifier.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size = 10, epochs = 100)"
    Model: "sequential_7"
    _________________________________________________________________
    Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
    =================================================================
    dense_16 (Dense)             (None, 12)                36        
    _________________________________________________________________
    dense_17 (Dense)             (None, 8)                 104       
    _________________________________________________________________
    dense_18 (Dense)             (None, 1)                 9         
    =================================================================
    Total params: 149
    Trainable params: 149
    Non-trainable params: 0
    _________________________________________________________________
    Epoch 1/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 4s 2s/step - loss: 21.5792 - mse: 21.5792 - mae: 4.6453 - val_loss: 21.1288 - val_mse: 21.1288 - val_mae: 4.5966
    Epoch 2/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 49ms/step - loss: 21.1630 - mse: 21.1630 - mae: 4.6003 - val_loss: 20.7178 - val_mse: 20.7178 - val_mae: 4.5516
    Epoch 3/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 37ms/step - loss: 20.7569 - mse: 20.7569 - mae: 4.5559 - val_loss: 20.3055 - val_mse: 20.3055 - val_mae: 4.5061
    Epoch 4/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 36ms/step - loss: 20.3392 - mse: 20.3392 - mae: 4.5099 - val_loss: 19.9005 - val_mse: 19.9005 - val_mae: 4.4609
    Epoch 5/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 39ms/step - loss: 19.9345 - mse: 19.9345 - mae: 4.4648 - val_loss: 19.5277 - val_mse: 19.5277 - val_mae: 4.4189
    Epoch 6/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 41ms/step - loss: 19.5620 - mse: 19.5620 - mae: 4.4229 - val_loss: 19.1644 - val_mse: 19.1644 - val_mae: 4.3776
    Epoch 7/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 44ms/step - loss: 19.1881 - mse: 19.1881 - mae: 4.3804 - val_loss: 18.8005 - val_mse: 18.8005 - val_mae: 4.3359
    Epoch 8/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 43ms/step - loss: 18.8242 - mse: 18.8242 - mae: 4.3386 - val_loss: 18.4356 - val_mse: 18.4356 - val_mae: 4.2936
    Epoch 9/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 41ms/step - loss: 18.4627 - mse: 18.4627 - mae: 4.2968 - val_loss: 18.0693 - val_mse: 18.0693 - val_mae: 4.2507
    Epoch 10/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 46ms/step - loss: 18.0987 - mse: 18.0987 - mae: 4.2542 - val_loss: 17.7013 - val_mse: 17.7013 - val_mae: 4.2072
    Epoch 11/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 43ms/step - loss: 17.7241 - mse: 17.7241 - mae: 4.2099 - val_loss: 17.3315 - val_mse: 17.3315 - val_mae: 4.1630
    Epoch 12/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 42ms/step - loss: 17.3476 - mse: 17.3476 - mae: 4.1650 - val_loss: 16.9598 - val_mse: 16.9598 - val_mae: 4.1181
    Epoch 13/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 42ms/step - loss: 16.9793 - mse: 16.9793 - mae: 4.1205 - val_loss: 16.5861 - val_mse: 16.5861 - val_mae: 4.0725
    Epoch 14/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 68ms/step - loss: 16.5996 - mse: 16.5996 - mae: 4.0742 - val_loss: 16.2160 - val_mse: 16.2160 - val_mae: 4.0268
    Epoch 15/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 47ms/step - loss: 16.2302 - mse: 16.2302 - mae: 4.0286 - val_loss: 15.8579 - val_mse: 15.8579 - val_mae: 3.9821
    Epoch 16/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 58ms/step - loss: 15.8659 - mse: 15.8659 - mae: 3.9831 - val_loss: 15.4963 - val_mse: 15.4963 - val_mae: 3.9364
    Epoch 17/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 48ms/step - loss: 15.5076 - mse: 15.5076 - mae: 3.9379 - val_loss: 15.1315 - val_mse: 15.1315 - val_mae: 3.8898
    Epoch 18/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 62ms/step - loss: 15.1399 - mse: 15.1399 - mae: 3.8909 - val_loss: 14.7637 - val_mse: 14.7637 - val_mae: 3.8422
    Epoch 19/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 66ms/step - loss: 14.7740 - mse: 14.7740 - mae: 3.8436 - val_loss: 14.3930 - val_mse: 14.3930 - val_mae: 3.7937
    Epoch 20/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 65ms/step - loss: 14.3982 - mse: 14.3982 - mae: 3.7944 - val_loss: 14.0197 - val_mse: 14.0197 - val_mae: 3.7441
    Epoch 21/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 63ms/step - loss: 14.0238 - mse: 14.0238 - mae: 3.7447 - val_loss: 13.6440 - val_mse: 13.6440 - val_mae: 3.6936
    Epoch 22/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 41ms/step - loss: 13.6475 - mse: 13.6475 - mae: 3.6941 - val_loss: 13.2662 - val_mse: 13.2662 - val_mae: 3.6421
    Epoch 23/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 38ms/step - loss: 13.2733 - mse: 13.2733 - mae: 3.6431 - val_loss: 12.8866 - val_mse: 12.8866 - val_mae: 3.5896
    Epoch 24/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 41ms/step - loss: 12.8926 - mse: 12.8926 - mae: 3.5905 - val_loss: 12.5054 - val_mse: 12.5054 - val_mae: 3.5361
    Epoch 25/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 43ms/step - loss: 12.5019 - mse: 12.5019 - mae: 3.5357 - val_loss: 12.1232 - val_mse: 12.1232 - val_mae: 3.4816
    Epoch 26/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 39ms/step - loss: 12.1143 - mse: 12.1143 - mae: 3.4804 - val_loss: 11.7402 - val_mse: 11.7402 - val_mae: 3.4262
    Epoch 27/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 42ms/step - loss: 11.7315 - mse: 11.7315 - mae: 3.4250 - val_loss: 11.3568 - val_mse: 11.3568 - val_mae: 3.3697
    Epoch 28/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 50ms/step - loss: 11.3485 - mse: 11.3485 - mae: 3.3686 - val_loss: 10.9734 - val_mse: 10.9734 - val_mae: 3.3124
    Epoch 29/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 50ms/step - loss: 10.9647 - mse: 10.9647 - mae: 3.3111 - val_loss: 10.5905 - val_mse: 10.5905 - val_mae: 3.2540
    Epoch 30/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 57ms/step - loss: 10.5837 - mse: 10.5837 - mae: 3.2531 - val_loss: 10.2085 - val_mse: 10.2085 - val_mae: 3.1948
    Epoch 31/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 66ms/step - loss: 10.1964 - mse: 10.1964 - mae: 3.1930 - val_loss: 9.8278 - val_mse: 9.8278 - val_mae: 3.1346
    Epoch 32/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 57ms/step - loss: 9.8153 - mse: 9.8153 - mae: 3.1327 - val_loss: 9.4490 - val_mse: 9.4490 - val_mae: 3.0736
    Epoch 33/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 61ms/step - loss: 9.4243 - mse: 9.4243 - mae: 3.0697 - val_loss: 9.0725 - val_mse: 9.0725 - val_mae: 3.0117
    Epoch 34/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 62ms/step - loss: 9.0554 - mse: 9.0554 - mae: 3.0089 - val_loss: 8.6988 - val_mse: 8.6988 - val_mae: 2.9490
    Epoch 35/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 86ms/step - loss: 8.6869 - mse: 8.6869 - mae: 2.9470 - val_loss: 8.3284 - val_mse: 8.3284 - val_mae: 2.8855
    Epoch 36/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 62ms/step - loss: 8.3051 - mse: 8.3051 - mae: 2.8816 - val_loss: 7.9616 - val_mse: 7.9616 - val_mae: 2.8212
    Epoch 37/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 49ms/step - loss: 7.9430 - mse: 7.9430 - mae: 2.8180 - val_loss: 7.5991 - val_mse: 7.5991 - val_mae: 2.7562
    Epoch 38/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 47ms/step - loss: 7.5777 - mse: 7.5777 - mae: 2.7524 - val_loss: 7.2414 - val_mse: 7.2414 - val_mae: 2.6905
    Epoch 39/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 50ms/step - loss: 7.2170 - mse: 7.2170 - mae: 2.6860 - val_loss: 6.8888 - val_mse: 6.8888 - val_mae: 2.6241
    Epoch 40/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 45ms/step - loss: 6.8613 - mse: 6.8613 - mae: 2.6190 - val_loss: 6.5420 - val_mse: 6.5420 - val_mae: 2.5572
    Epoch 41/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 40ms/step - loss: 6.5169 - mse: 6.5169 - mae: 2.5523 - val_loss: 6.2014 - val_mse: 6.2014 - val_mae: 2.4897
    Epoch 42/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 35ms/step - loss: 6.1802 - mse: 6.1802 - mae: 2.4854 - val_loss: 5.8675 - val_mse: 5.8675 - val_mae: 2.4216
    Epoch 43/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 32ms/step - loss: 5.8484 - mse: 5.8484 - mae: 2.4177 - val_loss: 5.5408 - val_mse: 5.5408 - val_mae: 2.3532
    Epoch 44/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 41ms/step - loss: 5.5165 - mse: 5.5165 - mae: 2.3481 - val_loss: 5.2217 - val_mse: 5.2217 - val_mae: 2.2844
    Epoch 45/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 33ms/step - loss: 5.2035 - mse: 5.2035 - mae: 2.2804 - val_loss: 4.9107 - val_mse: 4.9107 - val_mae: 2.2152
    Epoch 46/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 34ms/step - loss: 4.8858 - mse: 4.8858 - mae: 2.2096 - val_loss: 4.6082 - val_mse: 4.6082 - val_mae: 2.1458
    Epoch 47/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 39ms/step - loss: 4.5880 - mse: 4.5880 - mae: 2.1411 - val_loss: 4.3145 - val_mse: 4.3145 - val_mae: 2.0762
    Epoch 48/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 35ms/step - loss: 4.2917 - mse: 4.2917 - mae: 2.0708 - val_loss: 4.0301 - val_mse: 4.0301 - val_mae: 2.0065
    Epoch 49/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 39ms/step - loss: 4.0042 - mse: 4.0042 - mae: 2.0001 - val_loss: 3.7553 - val_mse: 3.7553 - val_mae: 1.9368
    Epoch 50/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 32ms/step - loss: 3.7338 - mse: 3.7338 - mae: 1.9313 - val_loss: 3.4904 - val_mse: 3.4904 - val_mae: 1.8671
    Epoch 51/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 43ms/step - loss: 3.4599 - mse: 3.4599 - mae: 1.8590 - val_loss: 3.2357 - val_mse: 3.2357 - val_mae: 1.7976
    Epoch 52/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 36ms/step - loss: 3.2049 - mse: 3.2049 - mae: 1.7890 - val_loss: 2.9914 - val_mse: 2.9914 - val_mae: 1.7283
    Epoch 53/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 45ms/step - loss: 2.9701 - mse: 2.9701 - mae: 1.7220 - val_loss: 2.7577 - val_mse: 2.7577 - val_mae: 1.6592
    Epoch 54/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 50ms/step - loss: 2.7272 - mse: 2.7272 - mae: 1.6501 - val_loss: 2.5348 - val_mse: 2.5348 - val_mae: 1.5906
    Epoch 55/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 42ms/step - loss: 2.5123 - mse: 2.5123 - mae: 1.5835 - val_loss: 2.3229 - val_mse: 2.3229 - val_mae: 1.5225
    Epoch 56/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 41ms/step - loss: 2.3037 - mse: 2.3037 - mae: 1.5160 - val_loss: 2.1220 - val_mse: 2.1220 - val_mae: 1.4550
    Epoch 57/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 48ms/step - loss: 2.0902 - mse: 2.0902 - mae: 1.4440 - val_loss: 1.9322 - val_mse: 1.9322 - val_mae: 1.3881
    Epoch 58/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 37ms/step - loss: 1.9124 - mse: 1.9124 - mae: 1.3808 - val_loss: 1.7534 - val_mse: 1.7534 - val_mae: 1.3221
    Epoch 59/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 34ms/step - loss: 1.7313 - mse: 1.7313 - mae: 1.3137 - val_loss: 1.5856 - val_mse: 1.5856 - val_mae: 1.2570
    Epoch 60/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 37ms/step - loss: 1.5732 - mse: 1.5732 - mae: 1.2517 - val_loss: 1.4288 - val_mse: 1.4288 - val_mae: 1.1929
    Epoch 61/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 41ms/step - loss: 1.4091 - mse: 1.4091 - mae: 1.1846 - val_loss: 1.2827 - val_mse: 1.2827 - val_mae: 1.1299
    Epoch 62/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 38ms/step - loss: 1.2716 - mse: 1.2716 - mae: 1.1246 - val_loss: 1.1472 - val_mse: 1.1472 - val_mae: 1.0682
    Epoch 63/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 34ms/step - loss: 1.1280 - mse: 1.1280 - mae: 1.0588 - val_loss: 1.0220 - val_mse: 1.0220 - val_mae: 1.0078
    Epoch 64/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 44ms/step - loss: 1.0087 - mse: 1.0087 - mae: 1.0008 - val_loss: 0.9068 - val_mse: 0.9068 - val_mae: 0.9488
    Epoch 65/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 43ms/step - loss: 0.8975 - mse: 0.8975 - mae: 0.9433 - val_loss: 0.8012 - val_mse: 0.8012 - val_mae: 0.8914
    Epoch 66/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 40ms/step - loss: 0.7812 - mse: 0.7812 - mae: 0.8798 - val_loss: 0.7049 - val_mse: 0.7049 - val_mae: 0.8355
    Epoch 67/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 45ms/step - loss: 0.6949 - mse: 0.6949 - mae: 0.8288 - val_loss: 0.6174 - val_mse: 0.6174 - val_mae: 0.7813
    Epoch 68/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 36ms/step - loss: 0.6063 - mse: 0.6063 - mae: 0.7734 - val_loss: 0.5383 - val_mse: 0.5383 - val_mae: 0.7288
    Epoch 69/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 43ms/step - loss: 0.5257 - mse: 0.5257 - mae: 0.7197 - val_loss: 0.4672 - val_mse: 0.4672 - val_mae: 0.6782
    Epoch 70/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 51ms/step - loss: 0.4560 - mse: 0.4560 - mae: 0.6691 - val_loss: 0.4036 - val_mse: 0.4036 - val_mae: 0.6294
    Epoch 71/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 50ms/step - loss: 0.3913 - mse: 0.3913 - mae: 0.6195 - val_loss: 0.3469 - val_mse: 0.3469 - val_mae: 0.5826
    Epoch 72/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 45ms/step - loss: 0.3373 - mse: 0.3373 - mae: 0.5733 - val_loss: 0.2968 - val_mse: 0.2968 - val_mae: 0.5377
    Epoch 73/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 44ms/step - loss: 0.2869 - mse: 0.2869 - mae: 0.5275 - val_loss: 0.2526 - val_mse: 0.2526 - val_mae: 0.4948
    Epoch 74/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 39ms/step - loss: 0.2440 - mse: 0.2440 - mae: 0.4849 - val_loss: 0.2140 - val_mse: 0.2140 - val_mae: 0.4539
    Epoch 75/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 39ms/step - loss: 0.2019 - mse: 0.2019 - mae: 0.4405 - val_loss: 0.1804 - val_mse: 0.1804 - val_mae: 0.4151
    Epoch 76/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 45ms/step - loss: 0.1736 - mse: 0.1736 - mae: 0.4055 - val_loss: 0.1512 - val_mse: 0.1512 - val_mae: 0.3782
    Epoch 77/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 33ms/step - loss: 0.1458 - mse: 0.1458 - mae: 0.3697 - val_loss: 0.1263 - val_mse: 0.1263 - val_mae: 0.3435
    Epoch 78/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 36ms/step - loss: 0.1192 - mse: 0.1192 - mae: 0.3320 - val_loss: 0.1050 - val_mse: 0.1050 - val_mae: 0.3108
    Epoch 79/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 42ms/step - loss: 0.1008 - mse: 0.1008 - mae: 0.3018 - val_loss: 0.0870 - val_mse: 0.0870 - val_mae: 0.2802
    Epoch 80/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 43ms/step - loss: 0.0838 - mse: 0.0838 - mae: 0.2716 - val_loss: 0.0719 - val_mse: 0.0719 - val_mae: 0.2516
    Epoch 81/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 45ms/step - loss: 0.0677 - mse: 0.0677 - mae: 0.2420 - val_loss: 0.0593 - val_mse: 0.0593 - val_mae: 0.2250
    Epoch 82/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 38ms/step - loss: 0.0582 - mse: 0.0582 - mae: 0.2186 - val_loss: 0.0490 - val_mse: 0.0490 - val_mae: 0.2004
    Epoch 83/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 36ms/step - loss: 0.0476 - mse: 0.0476 - mae: 0.1928 - val_loss: 0.0405 - val_mse: 0.0405 - val_mae: 0.1778
    Epoch 84/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 40ms/step - loss: 0.0381 - mse: 0.0381 - mae: 0.1687 - val_loss: 0.0336 - val_mse: 0.0336 - val_mae: 0.1579
    Epoch 85/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 45ms/step - loss: 0.0323 - mse: 0.0323 - mae: 0.1481 - val_loss: 0.0280 - val_mse: 0.0280 - val_mae: 0.1412
    Epoch 86/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 52ms/step - loss: 0.0269 - mse: 0.0269 - mae: 0.1291 - val_loss: 0.0236 - val_mse: 0.0236 - val_mae: 0.1280
    Epoch 87/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 40ms/step - loss: 0.0225 - mse: 0.0225 - mae: 0.1103 - val_loss: 0.0201 - val_mse: 0.0201 - val_mae: 0.1164
    Epoch 88/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 49ms/step - loss: 0.0187 - mse: 0.0187 - mae: 0.0980 - val_loss: 0.0173 - val_mse: 0.0173 - val_mae: 0.1072
    Epoch 89/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 46ms/step - loss: 0.0172 - mse: 0.0172 - mae: 0.0917 - val_loss: 0.0152 - val_mse: 0.0152 - val_mae: 0.0988
    Epoch 90/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 36ms/step - loss: 0.0161 - mse: 0.0161 - mae: 0.0883 - val_loss: 0.0136 - val_mse: 0.0136 - val_mae: 0.0923
    Epoch 91/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 34ms/step - loss: 0.0137 - mse: 0.0137 - mae: 0.0821 - val_loss: 0.0123 - val_mse: 0.0123 - val_mae: 0.0875
    Epoch 92/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 35ms/step - loss: 0.0123 - mse: 0.0123 - mae: 0.0804 - val_loss: 0.0114 - val_mse: 0.0114 - val_mae: 0.0839
    Epoch 93/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 38ms/step - loss: 0.0120 - mse: 0.0120 - mae: 0.0776 - val_loss: 0.0108 - val_mse: 0.0108 - val_mae: 0.0817
    Epoch 94/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 31ms/step - loss: 0.0117 - mse: 0.0117 - mae: 0.0795 - val_loss: 0.0103 - val_mse: 0.0103 - val_mae: 0.0805
    Epoch 95/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 35ms/step - loss: 0.0107 - mse: 0.0107 - mae: 0.0797 - val_loss: 0.0100 - val_mse: 0.0100 - val_mae: 0.0798
    Epoch 96/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 41ms/step - loss: 0.0114 - mse: 0.0114 - mae: 0.0819 - val_loss: 0.0098 - val_mse: 0.0098 - val_mae: 0.0796
    Epoch 97/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 43ms/step - loss: 0.0115 - mse: 0.0115 - mae: 0.0843 - val_loss: 0.0096 - val_mse: 0.0096 - val_mae: 0.0794
    Epoch 98/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 51ms/step - loss: 0.0112 - mse: 0.0112 - mae: 0.0840 - val_loss: 0.0096 - val_mse: 0.0096 - val_mae: 0.0792
    Epoch 99/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 47ms/step - loss: 0.0111 - mse: 0.0111 - mae: 0.0846 - val_loss: 0.0095 - val_mse: 0.0095 - val_mae: 0.0791
    Epoch 100/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 46ms/step - loss: 0.0102 - mse: 0.0102 - mae: 0.0834 - val_loss: 0.0095 - val_mse: 0.0095 - val_mae: 0.0790
    Epoch 101/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 45ms/step - loss: 0.0109 - mse: 0.0109 - mae: 0.0846 - val_loss: 0.0095 - val_mse: 0.0095 - val_mae: 0.0789
    Epoch 102/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 35ms/step - loss: 0.0106 - mse: 0.0106 - mae: 0.0839 - val_loss: 0.0094 - val_mse: 0.0094 - val_mae: 0.0789
    Epoch 103/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 43ms/step - loss: 0.0113 - mse: 0.0113 - mae: 0.0885 - val_loss: 0.0094 - val_mse: 0.0094 - val_mae: 0.0790
    Epoch 104/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 43ms/step - loss: 0.0103 - mse: 0.0103 - mae: 0.0861 - val_loss: 0.0094 - val_mse: 0.0094 - val_mae: 0.0791
    Epoch 105/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 48ms/step - loss: 0.0112 - mse: 0.0112 - mae: 0.0881 - val_loss: 0.0094 - val_mse: 0.0094 - val_mae: 0.0792
    Epoch 106/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 37ms/step - loss: 0.0114 - mse: 0.0114 - mae: 0.0899 - val_loss: 0.0094 - val_mse: 0.0094 - val_mae: 0.0793
    Epoch 107/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 38ms/step - loss: 0.0100 - mse: 0.0100 - mae: 0.0847 - val_loss: 0.0094 - val_mse: 0.0094 - val_mae: 0.0793
    Epoch 108/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 48ms/step - loss: 0.0112 - mse: 0.0112 - mae: 0.0885 - val_loss: 0.0094 - val_mse: 0.0094 - val_mae: 0.0793
    Epoch 109/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 49ms/step - loss: 0.0113 - mse: 0.0113 - mae: 0.0888 - val_loss: 0.0094 - val_mse: 0.0094 - val_mae: 0.0793
    Epoch 110/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 62ms/step - loss: 0.0114 - mse: 0.0114 - mae: 0.0896 - val_loss: 0.0094 - val_mse: 0.0094 - val_mae: 0.0792
    Epoch 111/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 51ms/step - loss: 0.0113 - mse: 0.0113 - mae: 0.0887 - val_loss: 0.0094 - val_mse: 0.0094 - val_mae: 0.0790
    Epoch 112/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 42ms/step - loss: 0.0109 - mse: 0.0109 - mae: 0.0867 - val_loss: 0.0094 - val_mse: 0.0094 - val_mae: 0.0790
    Epoch 113/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 58ms/step - loss: 0.0108 - mse: 0.0108 - mae: 0.0863 - val_loss: 0.0094 - val_mse: 0.0094 - val_mae: 0.0789
    Epoch 114/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 65ms/step - loss: 0.0105 - mse: 0.0105 - mae: 0.0870 - val_loss: 0.0094 - val_mse: 0.0094 - val_mae: 0.0789
    Epoch 115/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 63ms/step - loss: 0.0110 - mse: 0.0110 - mae: 0.0865 - val_loss: 0.0094 - val_mse: 0.0094 - val_mae: 0.0789
    Epoch 116/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 67ms/step - loss: 0.0111 - mse: 0.0111 - mae: 0.0869 - val_loss: 0.0094 - val_mse: 0.0094 - val_mae: 0.0788
    Epoch 117/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 55ms/step - loss: 0.0109 - mse: 0.0109 - mae: 0.0860 - val_loss: 0.0094 - val_mse: 0.0094 - val_mae: 0.0788
    Epoch 118/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 54ms/step - loss: 0.0112 - mse: 0.0112 - mae: 0.0871 - val_loss: 0.0094 - val_mse: 0.0094 - val_mae: 0.0788
    Epoch 119/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 60ms/step - loss: 0.0103 - mse: 0.0103 - mae: 0.0851 - val_loss: 0.0094 - val_mse: 0.0094 - val_mae: 0.0788
    Epoch 120/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 56ms/step - loss: 0.0108 - mse: 0.0108 - mae: 0.0857 - val_loss: 0.0094 - val_mse: 0.0094 - val_mae: 0.0789
    Epoch 121/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 62ms/step - loss: 0.0108 - mse: 0.0108 - mae: 0.0846 - val_loss: 0.0094 - val_mse: 0.0094 - val_mae: 0.0789
    Epoch 122/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 58ms/step - loss: 0.0103 - mse: 0.0103 - mae: 0.0851 - val_loss: 0.0094 - val_mse: 0.0094 - val_mae: 0.0789
    Epoch 123/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 59ms/step - loss: 0.0101 - mse: 0.0101 - mae: 0.0839 - val_loss: 0.0094 - val_mse: 0.0094 - val_mae: 0.0789
    Epoch 124/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 36ms/step - loss: 0.0112 - mse: 0.0112 - mae: 0.0874 - val_loss: 0.0094 - val_mse: 0.0094 - val_mae: 0.0789
    Epoch 125/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 37ms/step - loss: 0.0109 - mse: 0.0109 - mae: 0.0849 - val_loss: 0.0094 - val_mse: 0.0094 - val_mae: 0.0789
    Epoch 126/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 42ms/step - loss: 0.0109 - mse: 0.0109 - mae: 0.0850 - val_loss: 0.0095 - val_mse: 0.0095 - val_mae: 0.0789
    Epoch 127/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 61ms/step - loss: 0.0102 - mse: 0.0102 - mae: 0.0842 - val_loss: 0.0095 - val_mse: 0.0095 - val_mae: 0.0789
    Epoch 128/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 43ms/step - loss: 0.0098 - mse: 0.0098 - mae: 0.0816 - val_loss: 0.0095 - val_mse: 0.0095 - val_mae: 0.0789
    Epoch 129/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 47ms/step - loss: 0.0110 - mse: 0.0110 - mae: 0.0854 - val_loss: 0.0095 - val_mse: 0.0095 - val_mae: 0.0789
    Epoch 130/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 62ms/step - loss: 0.0111 - mse: 0.0111 - mae: 0.0859 - val_loss: 0.0095 - val_mse: 0.0095 - val_mae: 0.0789
    Epoch 131/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 53ms/step - loss: 0.0110 - mse: 0.0110 - mae: 0.0857 - val_loss: 0.0095 - val_mse: 0.0095 - val_mae: 0.0789
    Epoch 132/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 49ms/step - loss: 0.0108 - mse: 0.0108 - mae: 0.0843 - val_loss: 0.0095 - val_mse: 0.0095 - val_mae: 0.0790
    Epoch 133/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 54ms/step - loss: 0.0110 - mse: 0.0110 - mae: 0.0858 - val_loss: 0.0095 - val_mse: 0.0095 - val_mae: 0.0790
    Epoch 134/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 55ms/step - loss: 0.0113 - mse: 0.0113 - mae: 0.0867 - val_loss: 0.0095 - val_mse: 0.0095 - val_mae: 0.0790
    Epoch 135/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 64ms/step - loss: 0.0109 - mse: 0.0109 - mae: 0.0842 - val_loss: 0.0095 - val_mse: 0.0095 - val_mae: 0.0790
    Epoch 136/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 52ms/step - loss: 0.0113 - mse: 0.0113 - mae: 0.0867 - val_loss: 0.0095 - val_mse: 0.0095 - val_mae: 0.0790
    Epoch 137/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 51ms/step - loss: 0.0108 - mse: 0.0108 - mae: 0.0842 - val_loss: 0.0095 - val_mse: 0.0095 - val_mae: 0.0790
    Epoch 138/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 61ms/step - loss: 0.0107 - mse: 0.0107 - mae: 0.0829 - val_loss: 0.0095 - val_mse: 0.0095 - val_mae: 0.0790
    Epoch 139/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 46ms/step - loss: 0.0111 - mse: 0.0111 - mae: 0.0850 - val_loss: 0.0095 - val_mse: 0.0095 - val_mae: 0.0790
    Epoch 140/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 56ms/step - loss: 0.0108 - mse: 0.0108 - mae: 0.0836 - val_loss: 0.0095 - val_mse: 0.0095 - val_mae: 0.0790
    Epoch 141/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 52ms/step - loss: 0.0111 - mse: 0.0111 - mae: 0.0858 - val_loss: 0.0095 - val_mse: 0.0095 - val_mae: 0.0790
    Epoch 142/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 51ms/step - loss: 0.0102 - mse: 0.0102 - mae: 0.0838 - val_loss: 0.0095 - val_mse: 0.0095 - val_mae: 0.0789
    Epoch 143/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 63ms/step - loss: 0.0102 - mse: 0.0102 - mae: 0.0835 - val_loss: 0.0095 - val_mse: 0.0095 - val_mae: 0.0789
    Epoch 144/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 50ms/step - loss: 0.0112 - mse: 0.0112 - mae: 0.0864 - val_loss: 0.0095 - val_mse: 0.0095 - val_mae: 0.0789
    Epoch 145/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 50ms/step - loss: 0.0112 - mse: 0.0112 - mae: 0.0865 - val_loss: 0.0095 - val_mse: 0.0095 - val_mae: 0.0789
    Epoch 146/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 62ms/step - loss: 0.0109 - mse: 0.0109 - mae: 0.0844 - val_loss: 0.0095 - val_mse: 0.0095 - val_mae: 0.0789
    Epoch 147/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 50ms/step - loss: 0.0100 - mse: 0.0100 - mae: 0.0831 - val_loss: 0.0095 - val_mse: 0.0095 - val_mae: 0.0789
    Epoch 148/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 54ms/step - loss: 0.0111 - mse: 0.0111 - mae: 0.0856 - val_loss: 0.0095 - val_mse: 0.0095 - val_mae: 0.0789
    Epoch 149/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 57ms/step - loss: 0.0111 - mse: 0.0111 - mae: 0.0861 - val_loss: 0.0095 - val_mse: 0.0095 - val_mae: 0.0789
    Epoch 150/150
    2/2 [==============================] - 0s 45ms/step - loss: 0.0101 - mse: 0.0101 - mae: 0.0830 - val_loss: 0.0095 - val_mse: 0.0095 - val_mae: 0.0789
```

Comment: Try to change last layer to `Dense(1,activation="sigmoid")`

Comment: I've tried doing this, But I am getting the same accuracy. I made a mistake while asking the question. Actually the target variable I have is a numeric variable (like weight and height, say age).  What changes could I make in the ANN layers

Comment: Then you need to configure your ANN for **regression**, now it is for *classification* problems.

Comment: I've done that and shown the new code and output above. How can I improve the accuracy further

Comment: Your loss values seem low so the model is able to learn the data. Accuracy is not applicable in regression.

Answer (score 1):

You can have any number of hidden layers. To find the a suitable number we have to experiment. A bigger network is not always better.

And as @Frightera has suggested, change the last layer accordingly. We do so because it is a classification problem and not a regression problem. The output has to be binary as you have stated in your question.